# Move floatingactionbutton Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to move floatingactionbutton like in the picture?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `floatingActionButtonLocation` on `Scaffold`. While I can't find partial positioning method, you can create a custom class by extending `FloatingActionButtonLocation`

```dart
class CustomFabLoc extends FloatingActionButtonLocation {
  @override
  Offset getOffset(ScaffoldPrelayoutGeometry scaffoldGeometry) {
    return Offset(
      scaffoldGeometry.scaffoldSize.width * .25, ///customize here
      scaffoldGeometry.scaffoldSize.height - kToolbarHeight,
    );
  }
}
```

And use

```dart
return Scaffold(
  floatingActionButtonLocation: CustomFabLoc(),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked, //specify the location of the FAB
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    tooltip: "Centre FAB",
    child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
    ),
    elevation: 4.0,
  ),
```

Then you can add your bottom bar